# How to group multiple functions for parallel execution with Celery?

Tags: django, celery

I wanted to group multiple functions for parallel execution in Django within the `transaction.on_commit` function -however, I got `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object` I have tried to resolve this, but I now think I'm misusing one of the args. This was my initial approach:

```
# tasks.py

def func_a(keys: tuple, link_set: dict):
    # keys contain random integers as pk
    return 


def func_b(keys: tuple, link_set: dict):
    return 


def func_c(keys: tuple, link_set: dict):
    return
```

I tried to call these in my signal like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Foo)
def start_task(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ...

        keys = (instance.pk, foo.pk)
        link_set = {}
        transaction.on_commit(lambda: group([
            tasks.func_a.si(keys, link_set),
            tasks.func_b.si(keys, link_set),
            tasks.func_c.si(keys, link_set)
        ]).delay())
```

The 3 functions in `tasks.py` are independent of each other with no return value, putting them together into one incurs a little cost that I'd like to avoid- how best can I compose these functions for a faster response? Thanks

Comment: this article may help https://appliku.com/post/celery-groups-and-chords

Comment: thank you @JimmyPells turns out it was syntax error- ```Foo.objects.get(1)``` leading to ```TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object``` should've been ```Foo.objects.get(pk=1)``` also followed your link and ended up chaining the functions with the ```si``` signature, thanks